# How do I share H2 in-memory database across multiple Spring boot applications?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

This is a different scenario than the other answered questions. I have one Spring boot application (app #1) that uses embedded H2 in-memory database and exposes it as a server. My second Spring boot application (app #2) connects to the H2 server from app #1 and that works correctly. I can store and retrieve data from H2. Now here is the problem. I have a third Spring boot (app #3) and it connects to the H2 server from app #1. The connection works but it (Issue #1) clears all the data that had been stored previously by app #2. After this, now both app #2 and #3 can store and retrieve its data and also each other's data. Now I terminate either app #2 or app #3 and (Issue #2) the remaining app cannot continue using the H2 in-memory database. Are issues #1 and #2 normal behavior? If not, how can I fix them? I want my H2 data to stay as long as app #1 (the H2 server) is running, even if other apps have been disconnected and I don't want my data cleared when new apps connect to the H2 server.

Comment: What are the "connections" between the H2 server and the other two apps?  Do they involve some kind of context that attaches database cleanup behavior to it that occurs when it closes down? - If you are making, for example, Spring MVC REST calls to access the H2 database, there's no reason that those connections coming and going (they're stateless anyway) should affect the database context at all.  All that would matter would be the code that you're running in response to each REST call.

Comment: @Steve For app #1, here's the "application.properties" line spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb and for app #2 and app 3, here's the line: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9090/mem:mydb Here's the example that I followed: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-access-h2-database-multiple-apps

Comment: @Steve Here's the server code for app #1: 

@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public Server inMemoryH2DatabaseaServer() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createTcpServer(
      "-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9090");
}

Comment: Wow!  You learn something every day.  I never would have thought to do something like that, and didn't even know it was possible.  I would have thought that an in-memory database would have been private to the process that was hosting it.  

I suspected something like this by what you were asking.  Since I haven't done this, I don't know what behavior you should expect by doing so.  Maybe someone who has actually done this will come along.  Otherwise, I'd say look at the available docs and maybe Google for answers elsewhere.

Comment: I assume you already understand that you could implement a less coupled REST API and avoid your problems.  I understand if you want to try to get this method to work. - I've been Googling a little.  I don't see anything that suggests you'd not get the behavior you're expecting...just SHARING the database.  Strange.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I already Googled. What other way are you suggesting that I do it that is less coupled REST API?

Comment: Just create your own HTTP endpoints to implement functions that the apps use to modify and access data on the server. - It will be very different, as you'll have to implement your own database access API.  It isn't clear that that's the right thing for you.- I bet that what you are trying to do can work.  Maybe there are flags or config params when you make your connections. - seems strange to me that it's cleaning up at all when you close your connections.  Why would it do that?

Answer (score 3):

Found this in the docs here: https://h2database.com/html/features.html

> By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the
>   database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost.
>   To keep the database open, add ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 to the database URL.
>   To keep the content of an in-memory database as long as the virtual
>   machine is alive, use jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.

So I think your problem might be solved if you just set the db line in your application.properties file for app #1 to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

Please let me know if this fixes your problem, as I'm very curious.  Your description seems to suggest it's a bit more complicated than this...overlapping access from the two apps involved...but this sure sounds like the kind of parameter you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

i did it this way , register multiple H2 servers in you spring configuration

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public Server h2Server1() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9080");
}

// Second App
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public Server h2Server2() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9081");
}
```

then while connecting to H2 used below config

for file based H2

```
url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9081/<path to H2>
username=sa
password=sa
```

for in-memory H2 database

```
url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9081/<H2 database name>
username=sa
password=sa
```