# In-memory H2 be used with both R2DBC and JDBC?

Tags: spring, h2, liquibase, r2dbc

I'm trying to do a simple test app that uses in memory H2 like this.  I need the "datasource" t

```yaml
spring:
  liquibase:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:///testdb
    user: sa
    password: ""
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:h2:mem:///testdb
    username: sa
    password: ""
```

I can see in the logs that liquibase is being executed and created the table correctly but when accessing the data I am getting a message that the database is empty.

Comment: Because both operate on a different database. You have 2 instances in-memory with this configuration and not one. If you want to share the connection you will need to use a file based and server based solution. \

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273325/how-do-i-share-h2-in-memory-database-across-multiple-spring-boot-applications